# How to publish from python to arduino using rosserial

Tags: python, c++, arduino, ros

i am working on project using stepper motor and i want to send the position to the motors by using python code
and publish the position point from it to the Arduino

so far i have made a simple code to publish a point
this is the code

```````
import rospy
from geometry_msgs.msg import Point, Twist

global msg

msg= Point()
msg.x = 1500
msg.y = 500

rospy.init_node("motor", anonymous=True)
#publishing the msg
pub = rospy.Publisher('motor',Point, queue_size=10)
pub.publish(msg)
rospy.loginfo("motor postion:x=%d y=%d" %(msg.x,msg.y)) ``````
```````

then i made a Subscriber on the Arduino

```
#include <ros.h>
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <std_msgs/Empty.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/Point.h>
#include <AccelStepper.h>
#include <MultiStepper.h>

***
//defining motor pin
***
AccelStepper stepper1(1, X_STEP_PIN, X_DIR_PIN); 
AccelStepper stepper2(1, Z_STEP_PIN, Z_DIR_PIN);
MultiStepper steppers;

ros::NodeHandle nh;

void stepMotor1( const geometry_msgs::Point& msg){
    long positions[2]; // Array of desired stepper positions
    positions[0] = msg.x;
    positions[1] = msg.y;
    steppers.moveTo(positions);
    steppers.runSpeedToPosition();
    delay(1000); 
}


ros::Subscriber<geometry_msgs::Point> motor1("motor", &stepMotor1);


void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:

  stepper1.setMaxSpeed(1000.0);
  stepper1.setAcceleration(500.0);
  stepper1.setEnablePin(X_ENABLE_PIN);
  stepper1.setPinsInverted(false, false, true); //invert logic of enable pin
  stepper1.enableOutputs();
  
  stepper2.setMaxSpeed(1000.0);
  stepper2.setAcceleration(500.0);
  stepper2.setEnablePin(Z_ENABLE_PIN);
  stepper2.setPinsInverted(false, false, true); //invert logic of enable pin
  stepper2.enableOutputs();
  
  // Then give them to MultiStepper to manage
  steppers.addStepper(stepper1);
  steppers.addStepper(stepper2);
  
  nh.initNode();
  nh.subscribe(motor1);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  nh.spinOnce();
  delay(1);
}
```

when i try to run both code by `russerial run`
and python publisher.py

the msg dosnt publish to the arduino

the code work fine when i use rostopic pub /motor geometry_msgs/Point "x:0.0 y: 0.0 z: 0.0"

thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to run the publisher with: `rosrun rosserial_python publisher.py`.
Because the publisher also has to use the rosserial port.